# Javacsript Regular Expression matches number with maximum 10 digits with optional 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, regex, typescript

I have tried below regular expression to validate the number with following criteria

`/^\d{3,10}(\.\d{2})?$/`

a, number should be minimum 3 , maximum 10 (including .) digits and it may contain . and two decimal point

Examples

**valid numbers**

123

1234

12345

123456

1234567

12345678

123456789

1234567890

123.00

1234.02

12345.03

123456.04

1234567.05

**Invalid numbers**

1

12

1.11

1.1111

12345678.12

But my regex fail in case of
1234567890.00

Comment: `1234567890.00` seems fine.  https://regex101.com/r/cVmCiR/1

Comment: No, maximum 10 digits along with (.) , so before (.) it should be 7 digits eg 1234567.12 is fine

Comment: Well your reg expression says https://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5Cd%7B3%2C10%7D%28%5C.%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%3F%24%2F

Comment: @Keith I think you misunderstood. `123456789.00` has 11 digits, but OP wants to have a maximum of 10.

Comment: I think you could just do -> `/^\d{3,10}$|^\d{3,8}\.\d{2}$/`  IOW: one with 2 decimals and one without..

Comment: Is this number valid ? `22.22`

Comment: no minimum three digits want before the (.) eg 222.22 is valid and 22.22 not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?![.\d]{11,}$)\d{3,10}(?:\.\d\d)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![.\d]{11}$)` Negative lookahead, assert not 11 or more digits or dots till the end of the string
- `\d{3,10}` Match 3-10 digits
- `(?:\.\d\d)?` Optionally match `.` and 2 digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jfhpq4/1).

Comment: That matches -> `1234567890.00`

Comment: @Keith You are right, I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I see a contradiction in your description of 3 to 10 digits including `.`, and your invalid example `1.11`, which has 3 chars (digits and `.`)

Here is a regex with tests assuming you want to test for 3 to 10 chars (digits and `.`) :

```js
const input = [
  '123',
  '1234',
  '12345',
  '123456',
  '1234567',
  '12345678',
  '123456789',
  '1234567890',
  '1.23',
  '123.00',
  '1234.02',
  '12345.03',
  '123456.04',
  '1234567.05',
  '1',
  '12',
  '1.1111',
  '1.22.33',
  '12345678.12',
  '1234567890.00'
];
const regex = /^(?=.{3,10}$)\d+(\.\d{2})?$/;
input.forEach(str => {
  let valid = regex.test(str);
  console.log(str + ' => ' + valid);
});
```

Output:

```
123 => true
1234 => true
12345 => true
123456 => true
1234567 => true
12345678 => true
123456789 => true
1234567890 => true
1.23 => true
123.00 => true
1234.02 => true
12345.03 => true
123456.04 => true
1234567.05 => true
1 => false
12 => false
1.1111 => false
1.22.33 => false
12345678.12 => false
1234567890.00 => false
```

Explanation of regex:

- `^` -- start of string
- `(?=.{3,10}$)` -- positive lookahead asserting 3 to 10 chars
- `\d+` -- 1+ chars
- `(\.\d{2})?` -- optional `.nn` pattern
- `$` -- end of string